# Siteminder - Request of best references

Tags: siteminder

I am new at using **SiteMinder** and I would like to know ALL the things that I need to read and understand in order to use it. Please proportionate good references. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should start from the SiteMinder bookshelf.. and proceed from there. One of the good websites that you can look at is ssohelp.com.

You should definitely have some knowledge of web servers and the server platform that you are running SiteMinder on. There aren't a lot of public resources available for Siteminder, so you will need to do some digging through the CA Siteminder book shelf which is fairly thorough but sometimes topics are not arranged correctly.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBlox.com (parent company for ssohelp.com) has some good blog entries that describe some of the not so well documented features of SiteMinder.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that first you must *know* and *understand* how HTTP 1.1 works, with a good level of details. 
Learning Siteminder is a lot easier if you are knowledgeable enough with HTTP.